# How to create table with inner columns inside larger columns?

Tags: tables, columns, multicolumn

I want to create this kind of table with 3 large columns and at one point the column is divided to two smaller columns. Please note that the column not divided in the whole space.

**How can create the table with custom column sizes inside the larger columns?**

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|                |          A          |       Most Mon      |
-------------------------------------------------------------|
|  Methods       | Time [s] | RunCount | Time [s] | RunCount |
|----------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|    C           |          |          |    4     |    1     |
|    D           |          |          |    5     |    2     |
|    E           |          |          |    6     |    3     |
-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it's the other way round; initially you declare 5 columns and, in the first row, using `\multicolumn` you span some cells to occupy to of them.

In the following example, the packages [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) and [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) were used to improve the table formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{lSSSS}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Most Mon} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
Methods & {Time [\si{\second}]} & {RunCount}  & {Time [\si{\second}]} & {RunCount} \\
\midrule
C & 12.3 & 5 & 34.6 & 7 \\
D & 1.35 & 5 & 4.93 & 7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, instead of `S` you could use any other column type (and deal with possible alignments in other ways) such as `c`, `l`, `r`, or `p{<length>}`.

In a comment it has been requested to produce the table with the vertical rules; here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{| l | S | S | S | S |}
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Most Mon} \\
\hline
Methods & {Time [\si{\second}]} & {RunCount}  & {Time [\si{\second}]} & {RunCount} \\
\hline
C & 12.3 & 5 & 34.6 & 7 \\
D & 1.35 & 5 & 4.93 & 7 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is missing the vertical lines, I got odd looking lines when I tried to add them. How can you add them?

Comment: @hhh Yes, the idea behind booktabs is not to use vertical rules. If you want to add them, use the standard LaTeX commands for tables; please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another attempt where an `M` column type for centering is defined and the number alignment is used in the cell via `\tablenum[format]{num}`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}

%\begin{table}%[!htb]
%\centering
%\caption{The caption}

\begin{tabular}{*{6}{|M}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Most Mon}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Methods}  & Time [s]   & RunCount        &Time [s] &  RunCount\\ \hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{C}  &\tablenum[table-format=4.4]{3.5}  & &4        &  1 \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{D}  &\tablenum{3.75}   &                 &5        &  2 \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{E}  &\tablenum{23.6}   &                 &6        &  3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

%\end{table}
```